# How to find the number of unique values in a field using Arcade expression in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, arcade, arcgis-online-webmap

I have a field in my attribute named **Status** which has **three** uniques values, I am trying to get the count of the unique values, but I cannot get the count.

The field looks like,

| Status |
| --- |
| Work |
| Stop |
| Process |
| Stop |
| Work |
| Work |
| Process |
| Process |

The result I am expecting is:

```
 Work -    3
 Stop -    2
 Process - 3
```

```
Count(
    Filter($layer, "Status = '" + $feature.Status + "'" )
);
```

But I just get

> Execution Error:Timeout exceeded

What am I doing wrong here ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Arcade code will give you what you want:

```js
// Summarize data into a FeatureSet with two fields, Process and NumProcess
var aFS = GroupBy($layer, 'Process', { name: 'NumProcess', expression: '1', statistic: 'COUNT' });

// Build a string to display in pop-up by concatenating values
var sP = "";
for(var f in aFS){
  var p = f.Process;
  var n = f.NumProcess;
  sP = Concatenate([sP, p, " ", n, TextFormatting.NewLine]);
}
return sP
```

Answer (score 2):

[GroupBy | ArcGIS Arcade | ArcGIS Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/featureset_functions/#groupby) has been around long enough, since version 1.8, that most ArcGIS users have access to it.  In case someone doesn't have access to GroupBy, it is possible to get unique counts using core/original data types and functions.

```js
var d = {};
for (var f in $layer) {
    var k = Text(f.Status);
    if (HasKey(d, k)) {
        d[k]++;
    } else {
        d[k] = 1;
    }
}

var s = '';
for (var k in d) {
    s += Concatenate([Text(k),Text(d[k])], ',') + TextFormatting.NewLine;
}
return s;
```

Note that this approach will be noticeably, possibly significantly, slower than relying on GroupBy if that function is available.